IPTables NAT Explanation
Let's say I have a static LAN behind a NAT with the WAN network being dynamic. If I try to traceroute google.com from a board on the LAN, how does the board I'm tracerouting from know to send the packet to the bridging device on the NAT?
I'm trying to debug a problem like this right now. I have an OrangePi on a LAN behind a NAT created by another OrangePi.
But even I tcpdump on the OrangePi on the LAN when I traceroute 8.8.8.8 I don't see anything on the tcpdump and traceroute times out. I'm guessing I'm missing something fundamental here so any help would be appreciated.

How might the same thing work without NAT? It's hard to tell what you're missing exactly, but the most important thing is that a network shouldn't be thought of as "a NAT", i.e. you seem to consider NAT the building block of networks while in reality it's more like duct tape.

This is the most stereotypical software forum comment I've ever seen.

Thanks, I try. That doesn't really make it any clearer what kind of explanation you seek – are you asking us to explain routing from scratch, or do you already know routing and only need an explanation of NAT?
